# How to save data from firebase asynchronous request in a global variable?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

I know this has been asked on stack overflow several times but I cannot seem to find the answer I am looking for. I am trying to store data from a firebase database (using the observeSingleEvent(snapshot)) method in a global variable. See below code for details.

I've tried adding a completion handler and followed steps online, but doing so, the observeSingleEvent request stops working.

What I had before:

```
class ItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let listToUsers = "ListToUsers"

    var user: User!
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let defaultUser = User()
        ref.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
            defaultUser.uid = uid
            defaultUser.email = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""
            defaultUser.name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
            defaultUser.grad = value?["grad"] as? Int ?? 0
            defaultUser.number = value?["number"] as? String ?? ""
            defaultUser.image = UIImage(named: value?["image"] as? String ?? "")!
            completion(defaultUser)
        }) { (error) in
            print("hello")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        self.user = defaultUser
    }
}
```

What I tried after and still did not work:

```
class ItemsTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: Constants
    let listToUsers = "ListToUsers"

    // MARK: Properties
    var user: User!
    let ref = Database.database().reference()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let use = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
        self.getUserData(uid:use!) { (user) -> () in
            self.user = user
        }
}

func getUserData(uid:String , completion: @escaping (User) -> ()) {
        ref.child("users").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
                let defaultUser = User()
                defaultUser.uid = uid
                defaultUser.email = value?["email"] as? String ?? ""
                defaultUser.name = value?["name"] as? String ?? ""
                defaultUser.grad = value?["grad"] as? Int ?? 0
                defaultUser.number = value?["number"] as? String ?? ""
                defaultUser.image = UIImage(named: value?["image"] as? String ?? "")!
                completion(defaultUser)
        }){ (error) in
            print("hello")
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is self a class or a struct? We need a little more context to understand the issue here. If self is being passed by value, you may be modifying a second instance of self that was copied into the block context as opposed to the original reference.

Comment: self is just from the class. user is defined as: var user: User!, which is a class I made containing the variables above. the assignment occurs in a override func viewDidLoad() { function. I'll update now

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is asynchronous and the self.user = defaultUser in the first code block is going to be called way before Firebase has a chance to return data.

Data is ONLY valid within the closure following the Firebase call. So here's how to fix it. Oh, and remove that error code as it isn't needed.

Assume a user structure like this

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "some name"
    email: "some email"
```

and the code to read in uid_0 and populate a global (i.e. class var) user

```
class MyUser {
    var uid = ""
    var name = ""
    var email = ""

    init(aUid: String, aName: String, aEmail: String) {
        self.uid = aUid
        self.name = aName
        self.email = aEmail
    }
}

var user: MyUser!

func readOneUser() {
    let uid = "uid_0"
    let thisUserRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid)
    thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        //let uid = snapshot.key if you don't know the uid, it will be the key to the node
        let name = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "name").value as? String ?? "No Name"
        let email = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "email").value as? String ?? "No Email"
        self.user = MyUser(aUid: uid, aName: name, aEmail: email)
        print(self.user.name) //do something with the user here
    })
}
```

and this line

```
defaultUser.image = UIImage(named: value?["image"] as? String ?? "")!
```

needs to be addressed but I don't know what the intention is. It could end up being nil if this happens

```
defaultUser.image = UIImage(named: "")!
```

so you may want to populate it with a default image of some kind or provide error handling in case it is nil.